# UTC seconds and time format expression convertion in Python

Tags: python, time, utc, seconds

How to convert a seconds series since `2012-01-01 0:0:0` to a time format expression.

And the inverse? 
Convert a time expression, such as `2015-6-23 10:00:00`, to the seconds since `2012-01-01 0:0:0`.

Comment: [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime as dt

print (dt.datetime(2015,1,2) - dt.datetime(2015,1,1)).total_seconds()
print dt.datetime(2015,1,1) + dt.timedelta(seconds=3600*24)
```

#### the output

http://testedanswers.com/questions/-JsT943k5Y8lTp2dOb3s

#### Python documentation

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: `(dt.datetime(2015,1,1) + dt.timedelta(seconds=3600*24)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S")`